# Calling the same activity and creating camera in surfaceview

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

I've been trying to call the same class after a certain condition that uses camera live preview as background. But I'm getting an error.

Logcat:

```
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:258)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:235)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.example.gems.GamePlay.surfaceCreated(GamePlay.java:996)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:543)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:348)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-03 19:52:42.274: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm creating my camera like this.

```
Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;


getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();  
surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
         int height) 
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(previewing){
         camera.stopPreview();
         previewing = false;
        }

        if (camera != null){
            Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);                           
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            }

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);                           
            }

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);               
            }

            if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
            }

            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            try 
            {           
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);          
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Error", "Cannot start preview", e);    
            }
        }

}


        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {

                camera = Camera.open();  
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);

            } catch (IOException e) { }

        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (null == camera)
            return;
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        previewing = false;
        }
```

When I try to call finish then recall this same class again I'm getting the error at the top. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

"fail to connect to camera service" usually occurs when the camera is used by an other application or was not correctly released.

When you call Camera.open, you reserve the camera for you until you call Camera.release().
Here what is weird is that you call camera.release in surfaceDestroyed. So the camera should be released.

What I can advice you to do is to call camera.release just before calling finish().
you can also put a breakpoint on the line camera.stopPreview() in surfaceDestroyed.